# Elixir Macros: Get unquoted parameter value outside of quote

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I have a macro which gets a module name as parameter and I want to call a function on that module to get some data in order to generate the `quote` block.

Example:

```
  defmacro my_macro(module) do
    data = apply(module, :config, [])

    # do something with data to generate the quote do end
  end
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because the parameter value is quoted. I could fetch the data inside the quote block and act accordingly but that would put the whole logic inside the module that uses my macro which is quite dirty. I want to inject as little code as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the module out by pattern matching with its quoted form: `{:__aliases__, _, list}` where `list` is a list of atoms which when concatenated with a dot (use `Module.concat/1`) produces the full module name.

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro my_macro({:__aliases__, _, list}) do
    module = Module.concat(list)
    module.foo()
  end
end

defmodule B do
  def foo do
    quote do
      42
    end
  end
end

defmodule C do
  import A
  IO.inspect my_macro B
end
```

Output:

```
42
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't even think about pattern matching the quoted version.